# Angular and Leaflet add marker on click and get Coord

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, api, leaflet

I am trying to implement Leaflet in my angular 7 project i try to google the solution but nothing all the result is for angularjs or vanilla javascript.

**This is my ts file:**

```
 ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    //Init map & add tile
    this.map = new Map('map').setView([25.1220946, 56.3342466], 13);
    tileLayer('http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}').addTo(this.map);
    //onClick
    this.map.on("click", function(e){
    //Add marker
    this.myMarker = marker([e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng]).addTo(this.map);
    // console.log();
      console.log(`Your lat is : ${e.latlng.lat} and your lang :  ${e.latlng.lng}`);
    });
  }
```

**FYI** it's not duplicate, the same question is 5 years old everything is different now.

Answer (score 5):

To add a marker on map click you need to listen to a map click event once your map object is instantiated:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.map = L.map("map").setView([25.1220946, 56.3342466], 13);
    L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
      attribution:
        '© <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(this.map);

    this.map.on("click", e => {
      console.log(e.latlng); // get the coordinates
      L.marker([e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng], this.markerIcon).addTo(this.map); // add the marker onclick
    });
  }
```

Here is an example using Angular 8:
[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-and-leaflet-add-marker-on-click-and-get-coord-s7iif)

Comment: it's working but i want to remove the old marker when add new one onclick

Comment: You did not mention that behaviour in your question

Comment: In my opinion, the correct way to capture the click event is to use (leafletClick)="onMapClick($event)" in your HTML for map div. The current answer can only be used to play with map markers or the map itself. In my scenario, by clicking on the map, I added a new row to my reactive form with pre-filled long and lat. When I connect to the click event this way, I had a lot of bugs with detecting changes in newly created drop-down lists (they just didn't expand when clicked). When row was added outside of this.map.on("click"... everything was fine.

Answer (score 1):

As per **@kboul** answer we can achieve that (Add a new marker each time i click on the map with the right lat lng) with this lines of code :

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    //Init map & add tile
    this.map = new Map('map').setView([25.1220946, 56.3342466], 13);
    tileLayer('http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}').addTo(this.map);
    //onClick
    this.map.on("click", e => {
      console.log(e.latlng); // get the coordinates
      if (this.myMarker) { // check
        this.map.removeLayer(this.myMarker); // remove
    } this.myMarker = new marker([e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng]).addTo(this.map); // add the marker onclick
    });
  }
```